# "Would anybody like" vs. "would somebody like"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

I wonder if the following sentence is grammatical:

> Would anybody like another cup of tea?

Should it be *somebody* or *anybody*?

Comment: This is another strange case. Normally, a grammar book would say that we should normally use "any-", and we can use "some-" when we want to emphasize or expect "yes" as as answer. But in this case, I think that "Would somebody like another cup of tea?" sounds weird.

Comment: @DamkerngT. To me, "Would somebody like another cup of tea?" sounds it's asking an unspecified person to volunteer for the task of drinking more tea.

Comment: @snailboat Ahh, thanks. Now I can think of such scenes where there are nice young ladies trying to convince the passers-by in supermarket to taste the tea from their company.